# How to know that one email address is invalid using PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I want to implement one API for checking whether an email address exists or not. The logic is simple - if we are able to send the mail successfully then the address exists.

Now the problem is if the email mail does not exist then I get an error like this:

[image: screen shot]

How should I capture this "address not found" message found from the code programmatically? In var_dump I've got the following data but I'm not able to capture it.

```
//$mail var_dump output

{"status":"success","msg":"No"}object(PHPMailer)#2 (76) {
  ["Version"]=>
  string(6) "5.2.23"
  ["Priority"]=>
  NULL
  ["CharSet"]=>
  string(10) "iso-8859-1"
  ["ContentType"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "7bit"
  ["ErrorInfo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["From"]=>
  string(16) "dchatb@gmail.com"
  ["FromName"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Sender"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ReturnPath"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  ["Body"]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  ["AltBody"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Ical"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MIMEBody":protected]=>
  string(6) "test1
"
  ["MIMEHeader":protected]=>
  string(296) "Date: Sun, 15 Dec 2019 22:52:10 -0800
To: dchatb@gmail.com12
From: dchatb@gmail.com
Subject: test1
Message-ID: 
<2ed034787452c160678f074c1b601a0a@diceindiagroup.net>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.23 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

"
  ["mailHeader":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WordWrap"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Mailer"]=>
  string(4) "smtp"
  ["Sendmail"]=>
  string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
  ["UseSendmailOptions"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PluginDir"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Hostname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageDate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Host"]=>
  string(14) "smtp.gmail.com"
  ["Port"]=>
  int(465)
  ["Helo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPSecure"]=>
  string(3) "ssl"
  ["SMTPAutoTLS"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["SMTPAuth"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["SMTPOptions"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Username"]=>
  string(23) "info@diceindiagroup.net"
  ["Password"]=>
  string(10) "xxxxxxx"
  ["AuthType"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Realm"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Workstation"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Timeout"]=>
  int(300)
  ["SMTPDebug"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["Debugoutput"]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleTo"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleToArray"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["do_verp"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["AllowEmpty"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["LE"]=>
  string(1) "
"
  ["DKIM_selector"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_identity"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_passphrase"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_domain"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_private"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_private_string"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["action_function"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["XMailer"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["smtp":protected]=>
  object(SMTP)#3 (14) {
    ["Version"]=>
    string(6) "5.2.23"
    ["SMTP_PORT"]=>
    int(25)
    ["CRLF"]=>
    string(2) "
"
    ["do_debug"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["Debugoutput"]=>
    string(4) "echo"
    ["do_verp"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["Timeout"]=>
    int(300)
    ["Timelimit"]=>
    int(300)
    ["smtp_transaction_id_patterns":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["exim"]=>
      string(21) "/[0-9]{3} OK id=(.*)/"
      ["sendmail"]=>
      string(29) "/[0-9]{3} 2.0.0 (.*) Message/"
      ["postfix"]=>
      string(35) "/[0-9]{3} 2.0.0 Ok: queued as (.*)/"
    }
    ["smtp_conn":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["error":protected]=>
    array(4) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["detail"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["smtp_code"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["smtp_code_ex"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["helo_rply":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["server_caps":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["last_reply":protected]=>
    string(57) "221 2.0.0 closing connection r10sm6455443otn.37 - gsmtp
"
  }
  ["to":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(18) "dchatb@gmail.com12"
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["cc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["bcc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ReplyTo":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["all_recipients":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dchatb@gmail.com12"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["RecipientsQueue":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ReplyToQueue":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["attachment":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["CustomHeader":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["lastMessageID":protected]=>
  string(53) "
    <2ed034787452c160678f074c1b601a0a@diceindiagroup.net>"
  ["message_type":protected]=>
  string(5) "plain"
  ["boundary":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(35) "b1_2ed034787452c160678f074c1b601a0a"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "b2_2ed034787452c160678f074c1b601a0a"
    [3]=>
    string(35) "b3_2ed034787452c160678f074c1b601a0a"
  }
  ["language":protected]=>
  array(19) {
    ["authenticate"]=>
    string(35) "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."
    ["connect_host"]=>
    string(43) "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."
    ["data_not_accepted"]=>
    string(30) "SMTP Error: data not accepted."
    ["empty_message"]=>
    string(18) "Message body empty"
    ["encoding"]=>
    string(18) "Unknown encoding: "
    ["execute"]=>
    string(19) "Could not execute: "
    ["file_access"]=>
    string(23) "Could not access file: "
    ["file_open"]=>
    string(33) "File Error: Could not open file: "
    ["from_failed"]=>
    string(35) "The following From address failed: "
    ["instantiate"]=>
    string(36) "Could not instantiate mail function."
    ["invalid_address"]=>
    string(17) "Invalid address: "
    ["mailer_not_supported"]=>
    string(25) " mailer is not supported."
    ["provide_address"]=>
    string(54) "You must provide at least one recipient email address."
    ["recipients_failed"]=>
    string(45) "SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: "
    ["signing"]=>
    string(15) "Signing Error: "
    ["smtp_connect_failed"]=>
    string(22) "SMTP connect() failed."
    ["smtp_error"]=>
    string(19) "SMTP server error: "
    ["variable_set"]=>
    string(30) "Cannot set or reset variable: "
    ["extension_missing"]=>
    string(19) "Extension missing: "
  }
  ["error_count":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["sign_cert_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_extracerts_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_pass":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["exceptions":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["uniqueid":protected]=>
  string(32) "2ed034787452c160678f074c1b601a0a"
}
```

In the above there is a parameter : "invalid_address"

How to capture that?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else:

```
["Version"]=>
string(6) "5.2.23"
```

That's an old version of PHPMailer; use [the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Now to the actual problem. PHPMailer is not a DNS client, though it does do DNS lookups indirectly, but by the time it fails, you're already too far into the message sending phase, so your error handling will be more complicated. If you want to check DNS *before* you send email, you need to do it separately, for example by looking at the examples in notes on [this PHP docs page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php).

Having done an MX record lookup, you will need to follow that up with a lookup for the hostname it points to, for example (this code needs a recent version of PHP):

```php
[$local, $domain] = explode('@', $address);
$mxhosts = [];
$mx = getmxrr($domain, $mxhosts);
if (!$mx || count($mxhosts) === 0 || !dns_get_record($mxhosts[0], DNS_A)) {
    echo 'address is bad';
} else {
    echo 'address is ok';
}
```

That said, the PHP DNS function are a bit buggy and inconsistent, so I'd really recommend you use a well-tested package like [spatie/dns](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/dns).

Comment: But I don't want to see domain is ok or not. I just want to know mail address is ok or not. As some domain like gmail.com can be present but there is no guarantee that xyz@gmail.com is present or not. So i want to see after sending the mail. So it would be nice if get that invalid_address message or address not found error.

Comment: Sure, but the specific problem you asked about in your question can be detected *before* you try to send. If that fails you know for sure that sending to it will fail too. If it passes, then the only way you can check further is to try to send to it - but you know you won't get the domain error because you've already checked it.

Comment: You're effectively trying to say "how do I do DNS checks by sending email", and my answer says "you don't; you do DNS checks by checking DNS".

Comment: So, how can I get the invalid_address which I git after doing var_dump in $mail or address not found which we are getting in the mail after sending.

Comment: No no my intention is not to check DNS, my intention is to check the mail address exist or not.

Comment: The occurrence of `invalid_address` in that var_dump output is not a result of anything - it's just part of a list of translation strings and doesn't tell you anything. Checking DNS is **part of** checking whether an address exists; if the domain doesn't exist or doesn't have any mail servers, then you know it's invalid.

Comment: that's true. But what if domain is valid and mail id not valid. So there can be two test cases 1. domain invalid so mail id by default invalid 2. domain valid but mail id does not exist. So if we go for only mail id validation then two test cases will be satisfied. No need to check two cases then. That's why I'm willing to send a mail and trying to fetch the status of delivery.

Comment: Yes, but that was not the question you asked. PHPMailer will work for checking known-good domains - just try to send a message to the address, and catch any errors, like all the examples provided with PHPMailer do. There is also a simpler [SMTP code example that checks for existing users](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps) without sending, but I don't recommend doing that much as you may end up blacklisted for frequent incomplete connections.

Comment: I asked two questions : 1. How to capture the message "Address not found" which is shown in the picture and 2. How to capture that invalid_address which I've got in var_dump.

Comment: I've got another solution and changed it according to my need, https://diceindiagroup.net/dice_mail_api/index.php?email=dchatb@gmail.com Here I considered 1. Domain invalid by default mail invalid, 2. mail format invalid by default mail invalid 3. domain valid and format valid and mail valid

Comment: I answered both of those: 1) do the DNS query that captures that info separately; PHPMailer doesn't provide a mechanism to do that. 2) The `invalid_address` message in your var_dump is not an error. It will appear in an error message if you submit an address that has an invalid format, such as `user@example@example`. You can catch those errors by looking at the return value of `$mail->addAddress()`, and then `$mail->ErrorInfo` if it returns false. Your example does exactly the same as the SMTP code example I pointed you at.